# How can I import a package from within the package?

Tags: python, package

I'm writing a little package and I'm trying to include a demo script within it as an example.  However, I can't seem to import the package cleanly from within as though I was outside of it.

With a directory structure like:

```
trainer/
  __init__.py
  helper.py
  trainer.py
  [...more files...]
  demo.py
```

In `demo.py` I can't do `from .. import trainer` as it complains "Attempted relative import in non-package", despite the `__init__.py`.  If I move the demo up a directory and `import trainer` it works fine, but I was trying to keep it together with the package.

The hack-looking `import __init__ as trainer` works, but eeeew.

Importing the various bits from all over the module directly also works, but makes for a messy example.  Am I wholly misguided in my attempt or is there a better solution?

Comment: if its within the package all you need to do is `import trainer`

Comment: Isn't that the equivalent of `import trainer.trainer as trainer` (from outside the package)?  Is naming the package and module the same putting me up a tree?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to run `demo.py` as `python demo.py`, the problem that you're having is likely the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py).

What's happening is that Python's relative import mechanism works by using the `__name__` of the current module. When you execute a module directly, the `__name__` gets set `"__main__"` regardless what the actual module name is. Thus, relative (in-package) imports don't work.

To remedy this, you can do the following:

- Execute `demo.py` **as a module within a package**, like so: `python -m trainer.demo`. This should fix the error, but you'll still be importing the `trainer.py` module instead of the package.
- Now add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to `demo.py`, which will cause your imports to be absolute-only by default, meaning that relative imports have to explicit (as in, `from . import (...)`). This is force `import trainer` to import the entire top-level package, instead of the module.

Answer (score 0):

The way you organize the files, demo.py becomes part of the package, which might or might not be what you want. You can organize your files a little differently, moving *demo.py* outside of the *trainer* directory:

```
TopDir/
    demo.py
    trainer/
    __init__.py
    helper.py
    trainer.py
    [... more files ...]
```

Then, demo.py can do something like:

```
from trainer import trainer, helper
```